# Wrong month number when parsing datetime string with date filter

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to setup [logstash](http://logstash.net/) on my machine.

The problem is I can't correctly parse logdate using date filter:

Here is config file (`test.conf`) to reproduce this issue:

```
input {                                                                                                                
  stdin { }                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                      

filter {                                                                                                               
  date { match => [ "message", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" ] }                                                               
}                                                                                                                      

output {                                                                                                               
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }                                                                                        
}
```

And then after typing `2014-02-21 12:53:41` I get wrong month number in `@timestamp` field:

```
$ java -jar logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar agent -f test.conf 
2014-02-21 12:53:41
{
       "message" => "2014-02-21 12:53:41",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-01-21T12:53:41.000+04:00",
          "host" => "localhost.localdomain"
}
```

Could smb explain me what I'm doing wrong? Why the date pattern is not working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your configuration is wrong! Please correct the pattern.

```
date { match => [ "message", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ] }
```

The day pattern is "**dd**", not "**DD**". You can [refer](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) here for more information.

```
Symbol  Meaning                      Presentation  Examples
------  -------                      ------------  -------
D       day of year                  number        189
d       day of month                 number        10
```

After modify the pattern, My logstash can parse your log with your configuration.

Comment: You are right. I have tested your configuration last night but also can't found this problem. I just tried today and found it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Grok debugger at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/.

I was able to parse your expression using:

```
%{DATE:my_date}
```

You logstash file should look like:

```
filter {
  grok {
    pattern  => "%{DATE:my_date}"
  }
}
```

Then it will put it into my_date.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually the problem is not how to do it in another way, but why it's not working.